# Which one is more natural and correct: "the phone trials" or "the trials of the phone"?

Tags: grammar

Which one is more natural and correct: *the phone trials* or *the trials of the phone*? For example:

> **The phone trials** have showed that the phone is ready to be launched.
>
> **The trials of the phone** have showed that the phone is ready to be launched.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first one seems more natural.  The second seems to imply something the phone itself is experiencing, something akin to tribulations.
As in "the trials of drug use" which speak to the problems of drug use as opposed to "the drug trials" which would precede their approval for use.